# Using Vazco "Uniforms" in React-Meteor with Apollo GraphQL

Tags: forms, graphql, meteor-react, react-apollo, mantrajs

I am just starting to use [Vazco "Uniforms"](https://github.com/vazco/uniforms/) in my [Meteor Mantra Kickstarter](https://github.com/warehouseman/meteor-mantra-kickstarter), but I've hit a hard to solve puzzle :

```
<section class="field form-group">
  <label for="uniforms-0000-0002" class="control-label">
    Content
  </label>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="uniforms-0000-0002" name="content" placeholder="">
  </textarea>
</section>
```

That `textarea`, for example , as well as **all** other fields of all kinds on my form, is **not write-able**.

**Is there some mistake I might be making that blocks me from being able to write to the fields in the form?**

The JSX for it looks like this:

```
<BaseForm disabled={false}  placeholder={false} schema={this.bridge} >
  <div className="row-fluid">
    <div className="col-md-4">
      <NumField grid={6} name="pages" label="# Pages" value="0"/>
      <TextField name="title" label="Title" />
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-8">
      <LongTextField name="content" label="Content"
                     disabled={false} placeholder={false} />
     </div>
  </div>
  <ErrorsField />
 </BaseForm>
```

I set up the bridge definitions like this :

```
            : 
            : 
  this.schemaType = API_AST.getType('Book');

  this.schemaValidator = model => {
    const details = [];
  };

  this.schemaData = {
  };

  console.log("Book schema : ", this.schemaType);
  console.log("Schema validator : ", this.schemaValidator);
  console.log("Schema data : ", this.schemaData);

  this.bridge = new GraphQLBridge(
                         this.schemaType
                       , this.schemaValidator
                       , this.schemaData
  );
  console.log("The bridge : ", this.bridge);
}
```

The various `console.log( "..." )` instructions show :

```
Book schema :  GraphQLObjectType
     _fields:  Object
        _id:  Object
        author:  Object
        content:  Object
        pages:  Object
        title:  Object
        __proto__: Object
    _interfaces: Array[0]
    _typeConfig: Object,
        description: ""
        isTypeOf: undefined,
        name: "Book",
    __proto__: Object
```

... then ...

```
Schema validator :  function (model) {             // 39
  var details = [];
```

... then ...

```
Schema data :  Object
                __proto__: Object
```

... then ...

```
The bridge :  GraphQLBridge
                 extras: Object
                 schema: GraphQLObjectType
                   _fields: Object
                     _id: Object
                     author: Object
                     content: Object
                     pages: Object
                     title: Object
                     __proto__: Object
                   _interfaces: Array[0]
                   _typeConfig: Object
                      description: ""
                      isTypeOf: undefined
                      name: "Book"
                    __proto__: Onject
                 validator: (model)
                 __proto__: Bridge
```

Please let me know if the listings here are insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

It is writable, but you are not doing anything with it. According to the documentation [here](https://github.com/vazco/uniforms), `BaseForm` have to be used in the same way as a field, where `model` is the value and `onChange` is... The `onChange` of course. You probably want to use `AutoForm` or handle the form by yourself - there are few examples in the readme.

Comment: I have understood my mistake.

I was setting the `value` of each field, expecting the same behavior as an HTML form field: an editable initial value.

It seems that initial values, set that way, cannot be edited.

Comment: Also, I am only successful with AutoForm.  If I try to use ValidatedQuickForm, or any other the others, no field is editable.

Comment: As the name states `AutoForm` is handling changes by itself, _automatically_ and `ValidatedQuickForm` is a `BaseForm` with bound validation and auto-generation of the content.